# Can't end mission at MSV Strontium

Tags: mass-effect-2

I am stuck on MSV Strontium. The game tells me to hit F key to end the mission. I have hit the F key, no go. I can only replay the mission. I can not end it.

Please help. How do I end the mission?

Comment: Did you bind Melee to a different key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug if you have rebound your Melee Key to a different key. In this case, try to press "M" instead, since you have bound it to that key.